# Find over-payment amount using a three-table join

Tags: sql-server

How to find Overpayment value of only Client No 1 from below 3 tables using inner join? Each client wise I need to retrieve query.

For example 1:

Once I retrieved client 2 only, answer should be 0 because total he invoiced 300 and total he paid for invoice(s) 100 only so overpayment is 0 .

For example 2:

Once I retrieved client 1 only, answer should be 500 because total he invoiced 1500 and total he paid for invoice(s) 2000 only so overpayment is 500.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight-forward way, just linking these tables, to give the result.

The code below gives you the answers, with the bonus that, letting @ColId null, every Client will be processed.

You may think: it is computationally expensive!

Yes, it may seems so. BUT, check the complementary comments after the code snippet, plz.

```
DECLARE @CliNo INT

SET @CliNo = 1

;

WITH pay AS
(
    SELECT cli.[Client No], (pay.Amount - inv.Amount) AS DeltaPayment
    FROM
        dbo.[Client TBL] cli
            INNER JOIN(
                SELECT inv.[Client No], SUM(inv.Amount) AS Amount
                FROM dbo.[Invoice TBL] inv
                GROUP BY inv.[Client No]
            ) inv
            ON inv.[Client No] = cli.[Client No]
            --
            INNER JOIN(
                SELECT pay.[Client No], SUM(pay.Amount) AS Amount
                FROM dbo.[Payment TBL] pay
                GROUP BY pay.[Client No]
            ) pay
            ON pay.[Client No] = cli.[Client No]
    WHERE cli.[Client No] = @CliNo OR @CliNo IS NULL
)
SELECT
    pay.[Client No],
    CASE WHEN pay.DeltaPayment > 0 THEN pay.DeltaPayment
                                   ELSE 0
    END AS OverPayment
FROM pay
```

At first sight, it seems we are asking the SQL Server to `SUM` every invoice, `SUM` every payments, and only then computes any overpayment.

But, SQL Server 2012 is a hell of a smart beast.

Check the actual execution plan:

[image]

The SQL Server query engine is filtering the payment and invoice records BEFORE sumarizing them.

Hence, no performance penalty, although this is not exactly what you asked for - a simple query with tree direct INNER JOINS.

The complete code for this POC follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Client TBL]([Client No] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE [Invoice TBL]([Invoice No] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Amount MONEY, [Client No] INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY ([Client No]) REFERENCES [Client TBL])
CREATE TABLE [Payment TBL]([Payment No] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Amount MONEY, [Client No] INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY ([Client No]) REFERENCES [Client TBL])
go

INSERT INTO dbo.[Client TBL] VALUES(1), (2)
INSERT INTO dbo.[Invoice TBL] VALUES(1, 200, 1), (2, 100, 2), (3, 500, 1), (5, 300, 1), (6, 200, 2), (7, 500, 1)
INSERT INTO dbo.[Payment TBL] VALUES(1, 1000, 1), (2, 100, 2), (4, 1000, 1)
GO

DECLARE @CliNo INT

SET @CliNo = 1

;

WITH pay AS
(
    SELECT cli.[Client No], (pay.Amount - inv.Amount) AS DeltaPayment
    FROM
        dbo.[Client TBL] cli
            INNER JOIN(
                SELECT inv.[Client No], SUM(inv.Amount) AS Amount
                FROM dbo.[Invoice TBL] inv
                GROUP BY inv.[Client No]
            ) inv
            ON inv.[Client No] = cli.[Client No]
            --
            INNER JOIN(
                SELECT pay.[Client No], SUM(pay.Amount) AS Amount
                FROM dbo.[Payment TBL] pay
                GROUP BY pay.[Client No]
            ) pay
            ON pay.[Client No] = cli.[Client No]
    WHERE cli.[Client No] = @CliNo
)
SELECT
    pay.[Client No],
    CASE WHEN pay.DeltaPayment > 0 THEN pay.DeltaPayment
                                   ELSE 0
    END AS OverPayment
FROM pay
go
```